# How to subtract data from table2 to table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to subtract and add existing values in table like this

Table 1

```
id       q      q_out    
1        10         0    
2        10         0
```

Table 2

```
id     q    
1      2
1      1
2      1
2      2
```

I am expecting this output when i update table 1:

```
id     q      q_out
1      7       3   
2      7       3
```

but I get this output:

```
id     q      q_out    
1      8       2    
2      9       1
```

this is my query:

```
UPDATE 
    db_pro d 
    JOIN cart c ON d.pro_num = c.p_num 
SET 
    d.q = (d.q - c.q), 
    d.out_q = (d.out_q + c.q) 
WHERE 
    c.s_num='13-37478' and 
    c.class not like 'Books' and 
    c.remarks like 'On Process'
```

Comment: the problem sir is i got this output

id   q   out_q

1    8    2

2    9    1

can you help me sir?

Comment: i'm using mysql sir

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you update the query so that the names match the tables definitions above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the agregated values of table cart:

```
UPDATE 
    db_pro d 
    JOIN (
      select p_num, sum(q) q from cart 
      WHERE
        s_num='13-37478' and 
        class not like 'Books' and 
        remarks like 'On Process' 
      group by p_num
    ) c ON d.pro_num = c.p_num 
SET 
    d.q = (d.q - c.q), 
    d.out_q = (d.out_q + c.q)
```

Comment: Thanks sir but i got error on a query "Unknown columns c.s_num" in clause

Comment: Do you still get error? Because I used the column names from your query.